# How do you alter this so it accepts input from the user

Tags: java, jgrasp

```
public class OblongTester
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {  
   // declare variables
   Oblong myOblong = new Oblong();

   // use methods to set instance variables
   myOblong.setHeight(10);
   myOblong.setWidth(25);

   // use methods to retrieve values of instance variables
   System.out.println("Width: " + myOblong.getWidth());
   System.out.println("Height: " + myOblong.getHeight());   
   System.out.println("Area: " + myOblong.calculateArea());

   }
}
```

What i need is instead of having fixed values for setHeight and setWidth i want the user to be able to enter the height and width and then for the area to take the values for height and width multiply them together and produce the output for area for example

Enter the height: 10
Enter the width: 5
Area: 50.0

hope this is clear what i'm asking. Last time i got a wrap on the knuckles for not being specific.

Regards,

Mark

Comment: you can use scanner class for that http://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
public class OblongTester
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {  
   // declare variables
   Oblong myOblong = new Oblong();

   // use methods to set instance variables
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //create a scanner

   System.out.println("Enter the height: ");
   int height = sc.nextInt(); //get height

   System.out.println("Enter the width: ");
   int width = sc.nextInt(); //get width

   myOblong.setHeight(height);
   myOblong.setWidth(width);

   System.out.println();

   // use methods to retrieve values of instance variables
   System.out.println("Width: " + myOblong.getWidth());
   System.out.println("Height: " + myOblong.getHeight());   
   System.out.println("Area: " + myOblong.calculateArea());

   }
}
```

Comment: It may also be good to mention that `Scanner.nextInt()` doesn't read the newline character when reading the int, so if you have any nextLine() statements after the int reading, they will just get the newline from the nextInt() and no other input. To solve this you could stick an unused readLine() after the readInt() or use readLine() and parse to an int.